# How to get child element value separated by comma in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a list:

```
<ul class='class-name'>
  <li><p>value1</p></li>
  <li></li>
  <li><p>value2</p></li>
  <li><p>value3</p></li>
</ul>
```

I want to get `value1,value2,value3`. I'm using:

```
$('ul.class-name > li > p').text();
```

But I'm getting `value1value2value3`.

Can anyone tell me how to get a comma separated value?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could try this...

```
$('ul.class-name > li > p')
    .map(function() { return $(this).text(); }).get().join();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tTwJS/).

This gets all the `p` elements, iterates over them replacing their references with their text, then gets a real array from the jQuery object, and joins them with `join()` (the `,` is the default separator).

Comment: @Rashmi You've implemented it wrong. You've got something that is `toString()`ing the jQuery object. Check the fiddle.